# How to convert the inputs of a document.write from a proxy site. To something i can decode in python

Tags: javascript, python, web, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a list of proxies from a website. The port data of a proxy on the given website executes a script that contains the following.

`document.write(":"+(ZeroFiveSevenFive^FiveSevenOne)+(Eight5EightFour^Seven3Zero))`

and in the browser, the string `:80` is displayed.

If you run that command in the console opened at a webpage like StackOverflow. It returns

```
VM36:1 Uncaught ReferenceError: Zero1EightZero is not defined
    at <anonymous>:1:21
```

What I want is to feed `'(ZeroFiveSevenFive^FiveSevenOne)+(Eight5EightFour^Seven3Zero)'` string I get from my beautiful soup setup into a python function of some sort and return  `:80`

Comment: is `(ZeroFiveSevenFive^FiveSevenOne)` some sort of mathematical operation?

Comment: You need to use something like Selenium WebDriver to execute the JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @Barmar instead of the python requests library I used selenium and executed the script and got the answer I expected.

driver.execute_script('document.write(document.write(":"+(ZeroFiveSevenFive^FiveSevenOne)+(Eight5EightFour^Seven3Zero)))